# Is There A Way to Attach Keyboard to only one terminal?

Tags: raspbian

So to sum it up I have a web application that I'm launching to raspberry. I have a flask(python) app running on one terminal, while on another terminal is a barcode scanner running.

So next I have a hardware, a [barcode scanner](http://www.china-barcode-scanner.com/products/Yumite-barcode-scanner-433MHZ-wireless-laser-barcode-scanner-with-charging-station-YT-900.html) that scans a barcode (obviously) and inputs it as keyboard input, in otherwords it needs to be on that terminal in order for the barcode to be fed since it works just like a keyboard. So the flow might be like this:

**Flask Terminal is running as web app**

1. Open Scanner Terminal (terminal for barcode scanner), and then scan a barcode.
2. The scanner beeps and the scanned code was successfully fed to the Scanner Terminal which makes a post request to the flask app. And the flask app receives that input and displays it.

However currently, it is not possible to scan a barcode while not opening the terminal, this time I want to scan a barcode without opening the terminal, so that every barcode that I scan would only need to show on the interface.

An idea that I thought of is to attach the keyboard to work only on **Scanner Terminal** that way after I setup everything, the barcode scanner will only work for it.

Any ideas on how to do this? or any workaround similar to the target result that I want to send post request to the flask app, while not needing to be on the terminal. This would mean that the terminal is running on background as it send request to the flask app for every barcode scan.

And about it being, turned into serial mode, I dont know which of the options here is serial? I tried setting everything but just wouldn't work like serial. I used a wire barcode reader before this one, there was a simple option, USB Keyboard, Serial and P2P. this ones options are craze, pelase take a look at the pic. Can anyone guide me to how to set it to serial?

[image]
[image]

Comment: your link is broken - can the barcode scanner, like most can, be switched to serial mode

Comment: @JaromandaX hello sir, about this question, I actually tried a cheaper barcode scanner before this one, it only had three options, which is why I was able to switch to serial, however suddenly the serial stopped working which is why I bought something more pricier, but when I looked at the manual I dont see any "serial" mode.

Comment: @JaromandaX I edited the question and put up pics of the manual, thank you very much :(